# How can I delete from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have two tables employees and salary and I have prepared my query in such a way that once staff is deleted from the employees table, the staff salary is automatically deleted in the salary table.

How can I delete staff records from salary table once staff records are deleted from employees table?

Here is my SQL CODE:

```
$db->query('
 DELETE employees
      , salary 
   FROM employees 
 JOIN salary
  WHERE employees.id = salary.staffId 
    AND salary.staffId = :id'
 );
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to left join and to  change the where clause too

```
$db->query('
 DELETE employees
      , salary 
   FROM employees 
 LEFT JOIN salary ON employees.id = salary.staffId 
  WHERE employees.id = :id'
 );
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employees(id INT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employees VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE salary (id INT,staffId INT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO salary  VALUES(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)
> ```

> ```
> DELETE employees
>       , salary 
>    FROM employees LEFT JOIN salary ON employees.id = salary.staffId 
>   WHERE employees.id = 4
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM employees
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1c44224f4e9a68b7833eb591cdb45246)*

Answer (score 0):

It has been explained already how to `delete` from one or two tables using a `left join`.

I am answering because I think that you are missing an opportunity to use a built-in functionality of your database engine. This is your description of the context:

> I have prepared my query in such a way that once staff is deleted from the employees table, the staff salary is automatically deleted in the salary table.

You are describing a parent-children relation between employees and salaries: I would recommend just creating a *foreign key constraint* in table `salary`, that references table `employee`. You can set option `on delete cascade` on the key, so when a parent record is deleted, all corresponding children records are automatically dropped too (if there are no children, the child table is not affected).

You can add the foreign key constraint to your existing table like so:

```
alter table salary 
    add constraint fk_staff_id
    foreign key (staff_id)
    references employee(id)
    on delete cascade;
```

Then, to delete an employee, you would just do...

```
delete from employee where id = :id;
```

... And rest assured that any associated record in `salary` is automatically deleted.